# using zsh shell to install ruby-2.0.0-195 doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, zsh, zshrc

sorry this is my first time to post my question here. I am currently using zsh shell and I keep having trouble with installing ruby. While I run rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p195, it shows the error message as following,

```
➜  ~  rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p195
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p195.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/SamChen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.0.0-p195 - #downloading ruby-2.0.0-p195, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.0.0-p195 - #extracted to /Users/SamChen/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p195 (already extracted)
ruby-2.0.0-p195 - #configuring - using ZSH, can not show progress, be patient...
ruby-2.0.0-p195 - #compiling - using ZSH, can not show progress, be patient...
Error running 'make -j4',
please read /Users/SamChen/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p195/1368734705_make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

I read the old article about and check that I have `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` in the bottom of my `~./zshrc` file, but it still doesn't work.

Did somebody have a similar experience? 
Thank you for advance.

Comment: did you already install rvm earlier in bash? and now you use zsh or is this the first install of rvm?

Comment: You are sure ZSH is the problem and not a missing dependency for Ruby (e.g. outdated dev-libs)? What does `/Users/SamChen/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p195/1368734705_make.log` say?

Comment: the last message explicitly asks you to check  /Users/SamChen/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p195/1368734705_make.log

Comment: I had some issues as well, though not identical to yours.  I updated zsh and rvm to the latest, then it finally worked after some hours of work